# URL links consistent with menus?

Tags: menus, permalinks, links, sub-menu

I'd like to have a URL links consistent with menus on the page. For example:

- Menu1:

  - Submenu1

    - item1
    - item2
  - Submenu2

    - item3
    - item4
- Menu2:

  - Submenu...

    - etc..

The corresponding links shoud be:

- myweb.com/menu1/submenu1/item1
- myweb.com/menu1/submenu1/item1
- etc.

However, the links are

- myweb.com/item1
- myweb.com/item2
- etc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to create the hierarchy using page parents. So edit "Item 1" and set it's parent to "Submenu1". Then edit "Submenu1" and set it's parent to "Menu1" etc.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like that's the way to go. I will experiment. Please add a more detailed info as answer (not as comment) so I can accept it. Please mention where exactly to set "parents".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the hierarchy using page parents. Either use quick edit, or go through each page and [set it's parent](https://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-attributes/), so that you end up with:

- Menu1

  - Submenu1 (Menu1 is parent)

    - Item1 (Submenu1 is parent)

[image]